# SSH server display Motd instead of the Banner set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: ssh, motd, banner

My version of Ubuntu is:

> Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
>   Release:        12.04
>   Codename:       precise

I am try to setup my ssh server in order to display some warning message in the Banner. I followed the guide found here by the followings:

Allowing the Banner option in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

> Banner /etc/issue.net

and also

> service ssh restart

Then I tried to verify by duplicating my ssh session but my server gave me Motd as always. Any idea? I thought it might be related to chmod yet after setting it to 777 still not working.

root@casalab-Latitude-D530:/# ls /etc/issue.net -alt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1513  4月 30 08:36 /etc/issue.net
root@casalab-Latitude-D530:/#

Thanks a lot.

--Zota206

Answer (score 0):

The files you need to edit live in `/etc/update-motd.d`.
See the update-motd man page for details about how it works.